# Removing tricky phrase pattern through Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to remove patterns like this:

> Need for a reset 0 SHARES Share it! Share TweetBy Leandro DD Coronel

from a text data like this:

> Need for a reset 0 SHARES Share it! Share TweetBy Leandro DD CoronelWe Filipinos can’t solve our nation’s problems through incendiary debate, insulting one another or even threatening to physically hurt each other.We are currently a divided society. Sad to say,

The pattern of the phrase is that it starts with an upper case latter, there is a "*TweetBy*" in between, and the last character is a lowercase, followed by an uppercase letter (Not going to remove the uppercase letter). Now, I am having a hard time putting this into regex.

So far I was able to come up with:

```
[0-9A-Za-z].*Share TweetBy [A-Za-z].{1,50}[a-z].{1,1}[^ ][A-Z].{1,1}
```

But this removes the following:

> Need for a reset 0 SHARES Share it! Share TweetBy Leandro DD CoronelWe Filipinos can’t solve our nation’s

I only want to remove it until the last author's name, which is usually up to the last lower case character followed by an uppercase character.

Any suggestions or ideas would help.

Thanks

Comment: You need more specific rules than this to make it work.  E.g. what happens if a proper name appears in the tweet, such as `Tim`?  How would you know whether or not that is the actual start of the tweet?

Comment: I am not sure if you can write a regex that could recognize a proper name. But the author names usually ends at the last lowercase character immediately followed by an upper case character (no space). So this is the rule that I need to put into the regex.

Comment: In the case of my current data. It is ALWAYS the case thus, that is the exact rule I need for my regex

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You should show two examples: what you have and what you want to get. Without it it's only guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
[0-9A-Za-z].*?Share TweetBy.*?[a-z](?=[A-Z])
```

- `[0-9A-Za-z]` - Will match word character except `_`.
- `.*?` - Will match anything except newline. ( lazy mode ).
- `Share TweetBy` - Will match `Share TweetBy`.
- `[a-z](?=[A-Z)` - `[a-z]` will match a Lowercase letter. Positive look-ahead checks for uppercase letter.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDGsYP/4/)

Comment: Still does not work :( I am having a hard time figuring how to write in regex how to stop the pattern matching on the first time a lowercase character is followed by an uppercase character. In my example this is "lW" in the string "CoronelWe". so the regex should stop at "Coronel"

Comment: Checked it earlier. The pattern should stop at "Coronel". The regex captures until "We Filipinos", which should not. The rule should be first lower case character immediately followed by an upper case character (no space in between). So in the example's case, it should be the "lW" in the string "CoronelWe", so the regex I am thinking of should capture only until "Coronel". Sorry if it sounded confusing.

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck check now made some changes

Comment: We're closer now. The logic of the regex is correct but how come it only captures until "Corone"? It fails to capture the "l".

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck anyways happy to help :)

Comment: Yeah I already did. It says it is recorded, just does not show because of my reputation. Thanks again Code Maniac. You saved a life today haha